# No nodes added to index in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

The query I used to create the nodes is as follows

```
load csv with headers from "file:/sample.csv" as Jobs
create (TheJobs {Job_name: Jobs.insert_job, Job_type: Jobs.job_type, Owner: Jobs.#owner}) 
return TheJobs
```

and the command I used to create index was

```
CREATE INDEX ON :TheJobs(Job_name)

Output: Added 1 index, statement executed in 32 ms.
```

Then I tried to create relationships using the following query

```
Profile load csv with headers from "file:/Jobstofiles.csv" 
as rels2 
match (from :Files {Filename: rels2.Filename}) 
where rels2.Automatic or Manual="Automatic"
match (to :TheJobs {Job_name: rels2.Job}) 
create (from)-[:Is_triggered_by {type: rels2.Is_triggered_by}]->(to) 
return from, to
```

The execution plan shows nodeindexseek, but returns zero rows/matches when the data clearly matches

When I try to search a node from the index using the following query

```
PROFILE MATCH (node :Jobindex {Job_name: 'Job1'}) RETURN node

Output: 0 rows
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given your wording and queries, I get the feeling that you're not understanding what an index is and/or how an index works in neo4j. Can you provide details on the nodes that you created, and your understanding of what you think these commands are doing? That can either confirm or rule out my assumption, and allow us to better address the real issue.

Comment: So my understanding of an index is that based on a specific property (which is mostly a primary key) an index is created. This is like a redundant list of all values of the said property from all nodes which have that property. So when we look up a node based on a certain value of the indexed property, neo4j does not need to look up all nodes, instead looks only at the nodes pertaining to property values in the index.

Comment: I'm trying to create relationships using a load csv operation and here I'm trying to use the index to find the nodes. I executed a load operation for a set of 905 relationships. The un-indexed execution time was 7 minutes. The number of db hits to acheive this was 620 million as it was looking up all nodes. I want to reduce this using an index.

Comment: Yep! Neo4j uses indexes transparently, though, so you won't need to explicitly look up. Just create your index on the label+property and it will use that wherever it can for most operations.

Comment: So it is using the index but doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Right, because the index you created is only applicable on nodes with the :Jobindex label. Indexes can only be created and used on label+property. What you'll need to do, for all nodes that you expect to have the Job_name property that you want to index, set them with the same label, and create your index on the label+property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misread how indexes are used in neo4j.

Your creation of the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Jobindex(Job_name)
```

does not create an index called Jobindex on the Job_name property of all nodes, that's not how it works.

Instead, what you did was create an index on the Job_name property of nodes with the :Jobindex label. Meaning that this index is only used when you have a :Jobindex node with a Job_name property.

If you need to index on the Job_name property on a different kind of node, create an index with the label of that node. If you want to index on that property across nodes with differing labels, then consider if there is some more universal label you can apply to those nodes and then index on that (remember that nodes can have multiple labels).

As for using indexes, though there are ways to force usage of an index, these aren't common cases. Index usage is largely invisible to you, there is no special syntax for it, just write your match using the property that happens to be indexed, and the index will be used under the hood (if present) to speed up the lookup.

In other words, if you indexed on :Job(Job_name), and you wanted to look up a job by name, you'd query it with:

```
MATCH (job:Job{Job_name:"Software Engineer"})
...
```

Which is exactly how you would query it without an index.

I'd suggest [rereading the Schema section](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-schema) of the Cypher manual.

EDIT: Adding examples.

So, let's say that in the data you are importing, you expect to create nodes with the :Job label, which will have the Job_name property for fast lookup by name.

You'll want to create your index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Job(Job_name)
```

That way any operation that explicitly uses a :Job node and its Job_name property will take advantage of that index to improve the lookup speed, if possible.

But if you have a different case, needing to do the indexing over different kinds of nodes that have that same property, you still need a common label for that index. If this is just for data import, then you might cheat a bit, and create nodes with multiple labels, where one of those labels is the one you created an index on. Then, when you're done with your import, you can delete the index if it's not of any more use to you.

Comment: Hello, I actually want to index all nodes with the given property hence I used the index. However when I'm searching using the index giving a specific job name, it returns zero matches. I checked for data inconsistency but the data I loaded is 100 percent clean and consistent.

Comment: Got it, that matches my assumption. Indexes are always created on a label+property combination, you can't index only on a property across all nodes. And as mentioned above, there's really no such thing as looking up a node via an index, at least not explicitly. If an index is present on a label+property combination, queries and operations will take advantage of the index under the hood.

Comment: Ok so the query I used to create the nodes is as follows     load csv with headers from 
"file:/sample.csv"
as Jobs
create (TheJobs {Job_name: Jobs.insert_job, Job_type: Jobs.job_type, Owner: Jobs.`#owner`, Std_out_file: Jobs.std_out_file})
return TheJobs             and the command I used to create index was      CREATE INDEX ON :TheJobs(Job_name)

Comment: The query i used to create relationship is ----------- Profile load csv with headers from
"file:/Jobstoreqs.csv"
as rels2
match (from {Filename: rels2.Filename})
where rels2.`Automatic or Manual`="Automatic"
match (to {Job_name: rels2.`Job`})
create (from)-[:done_by {type: rels2.`done_by`}]->(to)
return from, to ------------ The profile plan shows no usage of index. It scans all nodes

Comment: Then I used this query ---------- Profile load csv with headers from
"file:/Jobstoreqs.csv"
as rels2
match (from :Files {Filename: rels2.Filename})
where rels2.`Automatic or Manual`="Automatic"
match (to :TheJobs {Job_name: rels2.`Job`})
create (from)-[:Is_triggered_by {type: rels2.`Is_triggered_by`}]->(to)
return from, to ------------- The execution plan shows nodeindexseek, but returns zero rows/matches when the data clearly matches.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, can you please add all of this to your description, and also double-check for any typos or omissions, and make it clear which parts are Cypher and which aren't. What stands out most to me, if what you have here is accurate, is that you aren't using labels on nodes (in job creation TheJobs is the bound identifier, there is no label) which results in full node scan and won't ever use an index. You need to use labels during node creation. Likewise your relationship query uses (to) and (from) without a label, you need to use labels here to take advantage of the indexing.

Comment: Likewise in your final queries. Here, you are using a label when constructing your to and from nodes (to:TheJobs). But it's clear from your previous create statements that you never created any :TheJobs nodes, you just created nodes without any label, so there's no way for it to take advantage of any kind of indexing. I edited my answer to give an example of proper usage for indexing given the types of nodes you plan on creating.